# Alternatives to subscribe for cold observable

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular2-observables, combinelatest

In combineLatest the method gets invoked only when we apply a ".subscribe()" to its end.
I wanted to know if there are other alternatives than adding subscribe to combineLatest method.

Comment: No. Observables are lazy by design. Nothing will happen without a `subscribe` call.

Comment: even PublishReplay will not work?

Comment: https://medium.com/@benlesh/learning-observable-by-building-observable-d5da57405d87

Comment: why you do not want to subscribe?

Comment: it was because i was using combineLatest and maaping the data using map and do method

Comment: You can also use `toPromise()` or `forEach()`  but I don't know what problem you're trying to solve so it doesn't really matter what you use...